# How to maintain login status with 2 websites in same server?

Tags: apache-2.2, login, gerrit

I've set up two gerrit servers for my department based on apache. With port 8660 and 8088 seperately.

But i found that, when some one log in 8088, 8660 will log out automatically, vise visa.

How can i log into these two gerrit at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the same domain name for both but a different port?

The issue might be the cookie path is the same for both sites so your login cookie is being overridden by the other site every time you login.

I think you want to change the 'auth.cookiePath' to anything other than the default value in one of your two gerrit deployments so that cookies are unique.

If you're using SSL for both sites setting 'auth.cookieSecure' to 'true' might also solve your problem.

I think the config file is located in '/etc/gerrit.config'

Reference: https://git.eclipse.org/r/Documentation/config-gerrit.html

Comment: Does auth.cookiePath have a format? I just change it into a arbitrary string, but now i can't log in...

Comment: if i set auth.cookiePath to "\", everything works fine. but if i set it to "\ABC", then i can't log into gerrit, why?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.infosystems.www.misc/6WXdQ2RFhG8/VvOUuR3FNAUJshows that it's impossible for me to distinguish cookies with port. Anyway , thanks